# Update quantity In PHP Session Based Shopping Cart

Tags: php, forms, session

Hello and a happy new year to everyone!
I work with php sessions...I have a cart...I want to update the quantity via session...
Here is my update action within the main file

```
if(isset($_POST["update"]))
    { 
        if ($_SESSION["item_id"] = $_GET["id"])
             { 
          $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
             }
    }
```

And here is the form within the foreach loop to display the checked product

```
  $total = 0;
     foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <form method="post" action="index2.php?action=update&id=<?php echo 
     $item["item_id"]; ?>">

     <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />
    <input type="submit" name="update" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="update" />
              </form>
<?php   echo  $_SESSION['quantity'];  //here I try to dislpay the new quantity that the user sets
 echo $item["item_id"]; ?></td>
```

Problem

It changes the quantity in all the products within the basket and not in the specific one I want.

Please forgive me because I am a new bye.

Comment: Ummm - that *looks* like you only have one single *quantity* value in the session ... and *item_id* is looking pretty scalar as well...?

Comment: Yes the session takes value from previous add to basket form. All I want is to change the value that the session has!

Comment: Sessions are user based. You only have 1 quantity session variable so if you change it then anywhere that you use it will have that value for that user's browser session. You'd need a different variable for each quantity or perhaps and array with the values.

Answer (score 0):

I added one more dimension to the $_SESSION array, using the item ID:

```
$_SESSION['item'][$_GET['id']]['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
```

Then when updating the quantity in the form:

```
echo $_SESSION['item'][$item['item_id']]['quantity'];
```